# I'm trying to create an temperature conversion program based on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php

My program alerts me when I first start it up, and it won't convert when I click the 'Calculate!' button.

```
<div id="input"> 
<form method = "post" action = "hw07.php" name = "form">
Temperature: <input type="text" id="num" name="temperature"> <br />
<input type="radio" name="con" value="far" id="far"> Convert to Fahrenheit 
<br />
<input type="radio" name="con" value="cel" id="cel"> Convert to Celcius 
<br />
 <input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculate!" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
<div id = "results"></div>

    window.addEventListener("load", link_events, false);  
function link_events() {
var temp = document.getElementById("num");
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = calculate(temp);
} 
function calculate(temp) {
if(isNaN(temp)){
    alert("Not numeric")
}
if (document.getElementById("far").checked) {
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Temperature is" + 
Math.round(num-32)*5/9;
}
 else if (document.getElementById("cel").checked){
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Temperature is" + Math.round(num*9/5)+32;
}
else
alert("choose a conversion");
return false;
}
```

I want it to alert me when I click the 'Calculate!' button and not when I start the program. It needs to print the converted value, but it's not even printing anything atm.

Comment: Do you have <script> ... </script> round your javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your code.

- `Element.onclick` property should be a function, not a function result value
- To get proper recalculation each time you press button, you need to get temperature value from input field inside function `calculate` (Also do not forget to parse it to Number type since it has String type)
- The last one is the mysterious `num` variable which should be `temp` obviously

All this problem are solved in the code below. Hope this helps.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", link_events, false);

function link_events() {
  document.getElementById("submit").onclick = calculate;
}

function calculate() {
  var temp = Number(document.getElementById("num").value);
  
  if (isNaN(temp)) {
    alert("Not numeric")
    return
  }
  
  if (document.getElementById("far").checked) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Temperature is " + Math.round(temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
  } else if (document.getElementById("cel").checked) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Temperature is " + Math.round(temp * 9 / 5) + 32;
  } else {
    alert("choose a conversion");
  }
  
  return;
}
```

```html
<div id="input"> 
<form method = "post" action = "hw07.php" name = "form">
Temperature: <input type="text" id="num" name="temperature"> <br />
<input type="radio" name="con" value="far" id="far"> Convert to Fahrenheit 
<br />
<input type="radio" name="con" value="cel" id="cel"> Convert to Celcius 
<br />
 <input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculate!" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
<div id = "results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    just remove this line 
      window.addEventListener("load", link_events, false);
    and change the link_events function
            function link_events() {
                var temp = document.getElementById("num");
                  calculate(temp.value);
            }
    and add onClick event to button 
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculate!" id="submit" onclick="link_events()">

also i corected this function

function calculate(temp) {
            if (isNaN(temp)) {
                alert("Not numeric")
            }
            if (document.getElementById("far").checked) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Temperature is" +
                    Math.round(temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("cel").checked) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Temperature is" + Math.round(temp * 9 / 5) + 32;
            }
            else
                alert("choose a conversion");
            return false;
        } 

num is not a  variable should be temp in Math.round()
```